# Проверка равенства значения переменной пяти символам

Tags: python, if, python-3.6

Как в python 3.6 инструкции (`if elif else`) проверить если переменная равна 5 символам?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте функцию `len("Строка")` она вернет значение количества символов в строке. В данном случае она вернет `6`. В конструкции `if` сравните с числом `5`: `if len("Строка") == 5`

Comment: В задаче написано, что нужно решение через конструкцию if; поэтому и предложил так

Answer (score -1):

```
s = 'hello'

if len(s) == 5:  
    print('True')  
else:  
    print('False')
```